# How to distribute analyzers as a nuget package

Tags: nuget, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a library with a few analyzers build using the roslyn engine. This analyzer library targets netstandard2.0

Now, I want to use this analyzers library inside my other project. It targets net45.
Everything works if include my analyzers as:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Include="MyAnalyzers.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, it does not work when I try to use my analyzers from my nuget feed:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="MyAnalyzers" Version="1.0.0">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>analyzers</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

The error (NU1202) I get, says that: Package MyAnalyzers 1.0.0 is not compatible with net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2) / win-x64. Package MyAnalyzers 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft's docs on .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0#select-net-standard-version), the earliest version of .NET Framework that is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 is .NET Framework 4.6.1 (although it also says that there were some bugs in this compat implementation, and it's recommended to use .NET Framework 4.7.2).

Therefore, your project using .NET Framework 4.5.2 is not compatible with the package, which is what the error message says.

You need to either upgrade the project referencing the package to use a higher version of .NET Framework, or you need to make the analyzer package multi-target `netstandard2.0` and also `net452` (well, I don't know if Roslyn supports analyzers on net452, but multi-targeting is a way to stop NuGet from reporting the NU1202 error).

Comment: The problem is, my analyzer library is developer dependency only. It is not something my project will be dependent in runtime on. That is why I can't understand why this compliance is being checked.

Comment: It's how NuGet works. What more can I say? StackOverflow isn't a place to report bugs, or request suggestions to product teams.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, nuget with analyzers needs to follow some specific internal schema. After I updated it to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/analyzers-conventions#analyzers-path-format guidelines, everything started to work as expected